# Saving images and documents in a database

Tags: angular, oracle-database

I'm developing a web application and i am using angular in frontend and springboot in backend with oracle database , so my problem is that i saved images and documents in my oracle database and it works , but i was wondering if there is a better alternative to manage documents and images , like a free electronic management documents .
Thanks for your help